# Ошибка при выполнении: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

Не могу понять где тут проблема, отступы делаю, но не запускает
в консоли пишет:
 `else: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

```
        if msg == "орёл":
            time_count = 3
            send_some_msg(id, "Вы выбрали Орёл!")
            for i in range(time_count, 0, -1):
                send_some_msg(id, "Осталось %d секунд" % i)
                time.sleep(1)
            random_monetka = randint(1, 2)
            if random_monetka == 2:
                send_some_msg(id, "Вы Выйграли!")
                monwin = monstavka * 2
                monwin = str(monwin)
                send_some_msg(id, monwin)
            else:
                send_some_msg(id, "Вы НЕ Выйграли!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту ниже, сделанному в Notepad++, Вы всё же комбинировали табы и пробелы, а это Python'у очень не нравится...

[image: пруф]

(Кстати, такое можно и у себя провернуть: Вид -> Отображение Символов -> Отображать Пробелы и Табуляции)